# Non object error in OOP

Tags: php

This is my bootstrap file:

```
class Bootstrap {

function __construct() 
{
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    //удаляем слеш с конца, чтобы избежать ошибки метода
    $url = rtrim($url,'/');
    //делим по слешу
    $url = explode('/',$url);
    //print_r($url);
    $file = 'controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';
        if(file_exists($file)) 
    {
    require 'controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';
        $controller = new $url[0];
    }
    else 
    {
    require '/../controllers/error.php';
    $error = new error();
    $error->classError();
    return false;
    }


    if
    (isset($url[2])){
        $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
    }
    else
    {
    if(isset($url[1])){
    if(method_exists($url[0],$url[1])) {
        $controller->{$url[1]}();
        }
        else {
        $error->methodError();

        }
    }
    }
}

}
```

As you see i created here an object, and called classError function:

```
else 
    {
    require '/../controllers/error.php';
    $error = new error();
    $error->classError();
    return false;
    }
```

Then i want to call another method in another place:

```
else {
    $error->methodError();  
    }
```

And it says: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function methodError() on a non-object in Z:\home\localhost\www\oop\mvc\mvc\libs\bootstrap.php on line 39.

When i create an other object for methodError method it works. The question is, why should i create another object, if i already create an one under it?

Comment: Your `$error` is created in an `else` branch. What happens if your code doesn't enter the `else` branch?

Comment: Oh yea, i just realized it lol

Answer (score 1):

Your an object is not created for else condition.

```
class Test {
    private $error;

    function __construct() {
      $this->error = new error();
    }

   public function test() {
      if( 1 == 1) {
        $this->error->methodError();
      }
      else {
            //
        $this->error->methodError();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your instantiation is in an else part... What if the code never enters the else part? Then `$error` will be undefined.

Btw. you won't create two objects, only write the code to instantiate the object twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this moving this line: `$error = new error();` above the if statements.  Then your object will be created regardless of what happens in your first if statement making the object available for your next if statement.

```
class Bootstrap {

    function __construct() {
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        //??????? ???? ? ?????, ????? ???????? ?????? ??????
        $url = rtrim($url,'/');
        //????? ?? ?????
        $url = explode('/',$url);
        //print_r($url);
        $file = 'controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';

        $error = new error();

        if ( file_exists($file)) {
            require 'controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';
            $controller = new $url[0];
        } else {
            require '/../controllers/error.php';
            $error->classError();
            return false;
        }


        if (isset($url[2])) {
            $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
        } else {
            if(isset($url[1])) {
                if(method_exists($url[0],$url[1])) {
                    $controller->{$url[1]}();
                } else {
                    $error->methodError();

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create first $error in a place where PHP code does not execute always.
As quick solution you may define $error again.

```
else {
    require '/../controllers/error.php';
    $error = new error();
    $error->methodError();  
}
```